# Distraction Feat

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm looking for a feat or trait or *something* that a PC (not a rogue) can take that would allow them to use a bluff check on a creature during combat to get them to look away from the party, making them flat-footed. I think Bluff vs Sense Motive could work, but then I couldn't have a mechanical means of making the enemy flat-footed.

I know the rogue has a couple of talents that are meant to distract the targeted creature ([Demand Attention](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/demand-attention-ex/) and [Distracting Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/distracting-attack-ex)), but these are more combat-centric, bring the attention back to the rogue, and only work for the rogue. Feint is a bit weird, it's either [completely useless](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?550048-Making-Feinting-work) or [the ruling isn't clear](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2unv7?Official-Ruling-Question-Feint).

I'm looking for a feat that's along the lines of:

> *Madja Look!*
>
> *You convince a target to look another way with a lie that made it more concerned than you and your party*
>
> Each day for a number of times equal to your charisma modifier, you can make a bluff check against an enemy or a group of enemies that you or an ally or allies are in combat with. The DC for the bluff check on one creature is 15 + 1/2 the target's level + Wisdom modifier, while the DC on a group of creatures is 20 + 1/2 the highest-level target's level + the highest Wisdom modifier within the group. A successful roll renders the enemy flat-footed to you and your allies for one round.
>
> You can only attempt this `talent/skill/feat/thing` on intelligent creatures. You cannot attempt this feat again on the same creature or group of creatures for 1 week.

Is there such a feat or special ability (racial/class) that can allows a player to use a bluff check to render a single or group of targets flat-footed for one-round?

Comment: Just to be clear, to paraphrase, the question is *Is there a feat that can render a group of foes flat-footed for 1 or more rounds?* Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes! If not a feat, is it a special ability a particular class might have? Ideally would use a bluff check. Thank you, I’ll edit the question

Comment: Could you explain how Improved Feint does not accomplish your goals (can only target one creature)? Have you looked at the feats that have Improved Feint as a pre-requisite (done your own research) to see if any of them do? Just thinking about my own experience, I can think of a few Feint-keyed abilities that approach what you want and I don't want this to turn into a list answer.

Comment: Also notable, Feint works (very poorly without investment) as written and that Paizo forum post is garbage, the VC's for that poor player just hadn't had to deal with that scenario before and ruled wrong. The GitP forum post isn't much better, but at least post #4 (johnbragg) outlines how little investigation the OP did and actually presents some information that may be of use to potential answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Investing in Feint can cause up to 6 targets to lose their Dex bonus

First, a note, Feinting causes opponents to lose their Dex Bonus, not become flat-footed. This is fairly nuanced, but it has benefits such as being able to be used against flying creatures (due to the poor wording on the fly skill). There are a [number](https://www.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?query=feint) of abilities that relate to Feinting. I found no abilities that allowed Feinting an entire area (perhaps that was considered too powerful with other options or the designers didn't realize there was a demand for such a capability).

---

The closest I found to the benefit you want is the Cavalier/Samurai alternative [Banner](https://www.aonprd.com/CavalierBanners.aspx) Knave Standard. At 14th level, as a Standard action...

> When the cavalier or samurai waves this standard, a number of allies equal to the cavalier or samurai’s Charisma modifier (minimum 1) within 60 feet can each attempt a feint against a foe she threatens as an immediate action.

---

Alternatively, the best option without homebrew seems to be combining alterations to Feint to allow you to use it up to 3 times per turn (as a Standard, Move, and Swift) and against up to 2 opponents each time with the benefits afflicting the target until the end of your turn.

Targetting two opponents it achieved with [Twinned Feint](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Twinned%20Feint)

> As a standard action, you can attempt to feint against a foe within your reach. If you succeed at the feint, you can make an additional feint attempt against a foe that is adjacent to the first one and also within reach. You can attempt only one additional feint per action with this feat. When you use this feat, you take a –2 penalty to your AC until your next turn.
> **Special:** If you have the Improved Feint feat, you can use this feat as a move action instead.

Next, you'll want the ability to Feint a greater range. There are a few ways to do this.

- [Ranged Feint](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Ranged%20Feint) feat - Feint within your entire range. The best option.
- [Archer Fighter](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Fighter%20Archer) archetype - Trick Shot (3rd level) option to Feint within 30ft using a bow
- [Gun Twirling](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Gun%20Twirling) Gunslinger feat - Feint within 30ft, but costs Grit. Fun imagery and a moderately useful secondary benefit.
- [Snakebite Striker Brawler](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Brawler%20Snakebite%20Striker) archetype - You Feint as a melee effect, but can do so while actually moving with your Standard and/or Move actions. Does not benefit Swift actions, but provides the ability to be where you need to be for it.

Finally, you'll want the ability to Feint with all 3 actions. Move action Feint simply requires Improved Feint, but Swift action is harder to attain.

- [Moonlight Stalker Feint](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Moonlight%20Stalker%20Feint) feat - Very heavy investment is required for this. Requires concealment, which can be accomplished with the Blur spell among other ways.
- [Rostland Bravo Swashbuckler](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Swashbuckler%20Rostland%20Bravo) archetype - Requires using an Aldori dueling sword, so Feinting must be done in melee. Otherwise works with Snakebite Striker multiclass or when you're surrounded.
- *[Sage Counselor Monk](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Monk%20(Unchained)%20Sage%20Counselor) archetype - Can Feint as a Swift action for Ki, but *only when performing a Flurry of Blows Full Attack.* Not useful to us.